# Query sum in more than one table

Tags: mysql, sql

How are you ?
I have mysql database.
I am trying to make a query a bit complex. I am going to write down what I have done so far.

## Query NO1

```
SELECT BONOD_AMOUNT, BONOD_DETAILS_ID
FROM  `BONOD_DETAILS` 
WHERE BONOD_ID
IN (
SELECT BONOD_ID
FROM BONOD_TABLE
WHERE USER_ID =16
)
```

The result is :

```
    BONOD_AMOUNT    BONOD_DETAILS_ID
    10000           3
    1520            4
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsK0H.png)

## Query No2

```
SELECT SUM( AMOUNT ) THE_SUM, BONOD_DETAILS_ID
FROM EXPENSES_TABLE
WHERE BONOD_DETAILS_ID
IN (
SELECT BONOD_DETAILS_ID
FROM BONOD_DETAILS
WHERE USER_ID =16
AND BONOD_ENABLE =1
) GROUP BY BONOD_DETAILS_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 AS THE_SUM, BONOD_DETAILS_ID
FROM BONOD_DETAILS
WHERE BONOD_ID
IN (
SELECT BONOD_ID
FROM BONOD_TABLE
WHERE USER_ID =16
)
AND BONOD_DETAILS_ID NOT 
IN (SELECT BONOD_DETAILS_ID
FROM EXPENSES_TABLE
)
```

The Result is :

```
 THE_SUM    BONOD_DETAILS_ID
 270        3
 0          4
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HryIP.png)

So, I would like to have a subtraction query from BONOD_AMOUNT in #Query1
and The BONOD_AMOUNT in #Query2

The Results can be:

```
 THE_SUB    BONOD_DETAILS_ID
 9730       3
 1520       4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is a small mistake in your #Query2. in the union all part. 
I think to work, you should do the followings:

```
SELECT 0 AS THE_TOTAL_SPENT , BONOD_DETAILS_ID
FROM BONOD_DETAILS
WHERE BONOD_ID
IN (
SELECT BONOD_ID
FROM BONOD_TABLE
WHERE USER_ID =16
)
AND BONOD_DETAILS_ID NOT 
IN (
SELECT BONOD_DETAILS_ID
FROM EXPENSES_TABLE WHERE USER_ID = 16
)
```

so, as JNevill answered. The query will be

```
SELECT A.TOTAL_AMOUNT-B.THE_TOTAL_SPENT AS TOTAL, 
A.TOTAL_AMOUNT, B.THE_TOTAL_SPENT,A.BONOD_DETAILS_ID
FROM
(SELECT BONOD_AMOUNT TOTAL_AMOUNT , BONOD_DETAILS_ID
FROM  `BONOD_DETAILS ` 
WHERE BONOD_ID
IN ( SELECT BONOD_ID
FROM BONOD_TABLE
WHERE USER_ID =16
)) A, 
( SELECT SUM( AMOUNT ) THE_TOTAL_SPENT, BONOD_DETAILS_ID
fROM EXPENSES_TABLE
WHERE BONOD_DETAILS_ID
IN (
SELECT BONOD_DETAILS_ID
FROM BONOD_DETAILS
WHERE USER_ID =16
AND BONOD_ENABLE =1
)
GROUP BY BONOD_DETAILS_ID
UNION ALL 
SELECT 0 AS THE_TOTAL_SPENT , BONOD_DETAILS_ID
FROM BONOD_DETAILS
WHERE BONOD_ID
IN (
SELECT BONOD_ID
FROM BONOD_TABLE
WHERE USER_ID =16
)
AND BONOD_DETAILS_ID NOT 
IN (
SELECT BONOD_DETAILS_ID
FROM EXPENSES_TABLE WHERE USER_ID = 16
)
) B
WHERE A.BONOD_DETAILS_ID = B.BONOD_DETAILS_ID
```

Comment: will try it now

Comment: Thank You very much

Comment: No problem. anytime

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to just join these two on the BONOD_DETAILS_ID and subtract that first column:

```
SELECT
    sub1.BONOD_AMOUNT - sub2.THE_SUM AS THE_SUB, sub1.BONOD_DETAILS_ID
FROM
    (
        SELECT BONOD_AMOUNT, BONOD_DETAILS_ID
        FROM  `BONOD_DETAILS` 
        WHERE BONOD_ID
        IN (
        SELECT BONOD_ID
        FROM BONOD_TABLE
        WHERE USER_ID =16
        )
    )sub1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT SUM( AMOUNT ) THE_SUM, BONOD_DETAILS_ID
        FROM EXPENSES_TABLE
        WHERE BONOD_DETAILS_ID
        IN (
        SELECT BONOD_DETAILS_ID
        FROM BONOD_DETAILS
        WHERE USER_ID =16
        AND BONOD_ENABLE =1
        ) GROUP BY BONOD_DETAILS_ID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 0 AS THE_SUM, BONOD_DETAILS_ID
        FROM BONOD_DETAILS
        WHERE BONOD_ID
        IN (
        SELECT BONOD_ID
        FROM BONOD_TABLE
        WHERE USER_ID =16
        )
        AND BONOD_DETAILS_ID NOT 
        IN (SELECT BONOD_DETAILS_ID
        FROM EXPENSES_TABLE
        )
    ) sub2 ON sub1.BONOD_DETAILS_ID = sub2.BONOD_DETAILS_ID
```

I would imagine that could be simplified, but since I can't see your data and have no idea about the relationship of your tables, I can't say for sure. I can say that this will get the results you are looking for though.

Comment: I would imagine your queries aren't doing what you say they are then.

Comment: Actually, there is a slight mistake in the query. I am sorry.